# nested relationship in hybrid_property in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `@hybrid_property` which references a nested relationship `self.establishment_type.establishment_base_type.name == 'QSR'`.  It works on a Location object as in `assert location.is_qsr == True`, but not in a filter.  I have tried adding a `@is_qsr.expression` function, but can't get any of them working.  How can I enable a filter such as `query(Location).filter(Location.is_qsr == True)`?

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'houses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    establishment_type_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('establishment_types.id')
    )
    establishment_type = relationship('EstablishmentType')

    @hybrid_property
    def is_qsr(self):
        if self.establishment_type:
            if self.establishment_type.establishment_base_type:
                return self.establishment_type.establishment_base_type.name == 'QSR'

        return False

class EstablishmentType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'establishment_types'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    establishment_base_type_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('establishment_base_types.id')
    )
    establishment_base_type = relationship('EstablishmentBaseType')

class EstablishmentBaseType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'establishment_base_types'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.has`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.has) on relationships:

```
@is_qsr.expression
def is_qsr(cls):
    return cls.establishment_type.has(
        EstablishmentType.establishment_base_type.has(
            EstablishmentBaseType.name == "QSR"))
```

This doesn't produce the most efficient query in the world (it does a `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)`) but a decent optimizer should be able to figure it out.